Is it possible to add buttons that have an instant question for FlowiseAI's chatbot
I love FlowiseAI but I'm not sure where I can ask this question.  Is it possible to add buttons that have an instant question?  Such as "What are your business hours"  or "Do you have any specials" to a FlowiseChatbot.  It would be great if such functionality could be added by reading an array or Google Sheet that could put that question into the prompt. Or if the instruction to dig into the Chatembed Github  https://github.com/FlowiseAI/FlowiseChatEmbed.
Like Shopify's online order chat at:
https://shop.wildrepublic.com/?syclid=ceac36fc-9300-44ee-9b6c-e8ec4d9ab3cb
Shopify's documentation
https://help.shopify.com/en/manual/inbox/chat-settings-and-appearance/instant-answers

I just started with Flowise and I saw in a tutorial, I Think you are looking for "Starter prompts", these will allow you to have the same initial buttons like the chat in shopify and have already a preconfiguration to return info.
I saw this thread in Github: https://github.com/FlowiseAI/Flowise/discussions/1643
